# Does $\frac{\overline{z}^2}{z}$ go to zero as z goes to 0?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I am trying to prove something and I need $\frac{\overline{z}^2}{z}$ go to zero  as z tends to 0 to get the result. Is this true? z is a complex number

Thanks

Comment: **Hint:** Consider the absolute value of the function.

Comment: hehe, that was easy!! Thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes since

$$\left|\frac{\overline z^2}{z}\right|=|z|\xrightarrow{z\to0}0$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true. If you write $z$ as $re^{i\theta}$ then you will have:

$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{{\bar z} ^2}{z}=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{r^2e^{-i2\theta}}{re^{i\theta}}=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} re^{-i3\theta}=0$

Note that you cannot write $z$ as $x+iy$ and take the limit as $x\rightarrow 0$ and $y\rightarrow 0$, since you are in the plane and you must approach to the point from all directions. This fact has been inserted in the phase argument of $z$ as $\theta$. As you see the final term in the limitation will go to zero regardless of the value of $\theta$.